# No transparent background in the navigated routing Component

Tags: react-native

I have a very basic app and I am using [ex-navigation](https://github.com/exponent/ex-navigation) for navigation.

App.js (*note the* `backgroundColor`):

```
export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'lightblue'}}>
                <TabEntry/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

TabEntry:

```
const Router = createRouter(() => ({
    notification: () => Notification,
}));

const defaultRouteConfig = {
    navigationBar: {
        title: 'notify',
        tintColor: 'blue',
        backgroundColor: 'green',
    },
};

export default class TabEntry extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <NavigationProvider router={Router}>
                <StackNavigation
                    initialRoute={Router.getRoute('notification')}
                    defaultRouteConfig={defaultRouteConfig}
                />
            </NavigationProvider>
        )
    }
}

class Notification extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>NOTIFICATION!!!</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Since, there is a `backgroundColor` in the parent Component, but no backgroundColor in its child component, it should have displayed a lightblue background. But instead the background is white. How can I make it transparent?

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting a `backgroundColor: 'transparent'` in the `<Text>` style.

So do this:

```
<Text style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}>NOTIFICATION!!!</Text>
```

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7964

Comment: No, this didn't help.